# Querying the VMware vCenter Database (VCDB) to calculate storage capacity

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Attempting to figure out the storage capacity within a VBlock so I can further look into it's usage by host and vm.

VBlock -- It's a pre-setup environment that allows for infrastructure virtualization at scale with parts from VMware, Cisco, and EMC

http://www.vce.com/products/vblock/overview

VMware saves data in the VIM_VCDB database which isn't entirely documented so if anyone has any guidance or ideally, is aware of which tables can produce the storage capacity of the vblock would be quite helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with the Storage Views in vCenter?

Comment: Storage views? Can you elaborate? @ewwhite

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't access the database directly if I was you. VMware might change the schema any time if they think it necessary. (That's why there's no documentation: You're not *supposed* to access the DB directly.) Try to get the information you need via [PowerCLI](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/), [Ruby vSphere Console](https://labs.vmware.com/flings/rvc) or something similar.

There are also libs to access the vSphere API like [VI Java API](http://vijava.sourceforge.net/) or [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) that you can use, but they are quite complex.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will only be running simple sql queries against the existing database, probably just select statements so there's not going to be any alternation of the data. @mario-lenz

Comment: @andi I didn't expect you to alter any data since you explicitly asked how to get data out of the database. However, I've had a look at the DB and think you chose the hard way. I've had a look at the DB when troubleshooting and getting data out of vCenter via the official API is far easier. Plus: It'll work with the next version, too, while you have no guarantee that the DB schema stays stable.

Comment: I have to second this answer, why go through SQL through this?  VMware's powercli would be way easier to get this data than SQL.

Comment: Because that data can be used for capacity planning and written to Excel etc.. @EricC.Singer

Answer (score -2):

The below link helped solve the issues I was having.

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/querying-the-vmware-vcenter-database-vcdb-for-performance-and-configuration-information/